# Wordpress Post Meta only working for one post in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Only the first post I created is providing the url in this loop, all followings posts I create don't show the url as existing.

```
global $post;
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'logos',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);
echo "<div class='ssslider-{$slider['id']}'>";
foreach($posts as $p){

    $company_url = get_post_meta($p,"company_url",true);
    $title = get_the_title($p);
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($p);
    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

    echo "<div style='margin:0px 40px;overflow:hidden;'><a href='{$company_url}' target='_blank'><img style='height:100px;' src='{$thumb_url}' alt='{$title}'/></a></div>";
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Is the post meta set on those posts? It also looks like you're passing the post object to `get_post_meta()` vs `$p->ID` to pass just the ID.

Comment: Yes the post meta is set on those posts, the post object as $p is only the id of the post.

Comment: Remove the `fields` prop from the array, and print_r `$posts`. You'll be able to see if the post meta is set on those posts.

Comment: yep you are right, I edited something after I created the first post changing the url value ... idiot mistake.. Thanks

Comment: Cool. We've all been there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's more common to use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this, [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) should work just fine.

It looks like the issue is in your use of [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

The first argument is expected to be the **Post ID** and it looks like you're passing a **WP_Post Object**.

Note, [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) should take the ID as well, but are stated to also accept a WP_Post Object.

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'      => 'logos',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids'
]);

echo "<div class='ssslider-{$slider['id']}'>";
    foreach( $posts as $p ){
        $company_url = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'company_url', true );
        $title       = get_the_title( $p->ID );
        $thumb_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id( $p->ID );
        $thumb_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
        $thumb_url   = $thumb_array[0];

        echo "<div style='margin:0px 40px;overflow:hidden;'><a href='{$company_url}' target='_blank'><img style='height:100px;' src='{$thumb_url}' alt='{$title}'/></a></div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: 'fields' is telling it to only return the ids
so if you var_dump($p) you will find 4 int's
when I change it your way and remove the fields option, it still returns the same exact data, missing all url except the very first one.

Comment: Whoops I didn't even catch that argument in there. If you do `var_dump($p);` in your loop, you're sure each `$p` equals the int value of the ID? And that each one has `company_url` set? If so, you may need to change to [`get_post_custom()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) instead. `$meta = get_post_custom( $p );` and `$company_url = $meta['company_url'][0];`